TensorFlow Addons (TFA) replacement
when I run my code that include the below function, I got error because TensorFlow Addons Wind Down.
What is the replacement for tfa ?
class SupervisedContrastiveLoss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, temperature=1, name=None):
        super(SupervisedContrastiveLoss, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.temperature = temperature

    def __call__(self, labels, feature_vectors, sample_weight=None):
        feature_vectors_normalized = tf.math.l2_normalize(feature_vectors, axis=1)
        logits = tf.divide(
            tf.matmul(
                feature_vectors_normalized, tf.transpose(feature_vectors_normalized)
            ),
            self.temperature,
        )
        return tfa.losses.npairs_loss(tf.squeeze(labels), logits)


To replace tfa.losses.npairs_loss, you can implement the NPairs loss directly using TensorFlow operations. Here's how you can do it:CODE_GIST,This implementation directly calculates the NPairs loss without relying on TensorFlow Addons. Make sure to adjust it according to your specific requirements.
